# typedef'd array of pointers - copying values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, typedef

Good day,

I have a few simple typedefs like so:

```
typedef int dataType;
typedef dataType* arrayOfNPointers[N];
```

So, `dataType` represents `int`, and the type `arrayOfNPointers` represents an array of `N` pointers to `int`'s.

Am I able to reliably perform a deep copy of the contents of one of these arrays to another like so:

```
#define N (2)
arrayOfNPointers a1 = { 1, 2};
arrayOfNPointers a2;

a2 = a1;    // Safe?
```

I know that I can directly copy struct's like this, and I know that in general, if I were to try to assign this with `int*` pointers, it would just qualify as a "shallow copy".

In this case, will I end up with two independent fixed-size arrays that contain the elements `{1, 2}`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, **watch out:**

```
arrayOfNPointers a1 = {1, 2};
```

As far as I can tell, this is initialising pointers as if they were integers. This cannot end well. (I'll deal with this more fully later.)

But anyway:

> Safe?

Nope. `a1` and `a2` are both arrays; this means that, among other things, they cannot be assigned to.

```
   a2 = a1;
// ^^^^ WRONG
```

Even if this *was* possible [e.g. if they were pointers], this wouldn't even be a shallow copy - the two [arrays that we are pretending are] pointers would point at the same block of memory. [Only structs can be shallow-copied this way.]

A proper deep copy *of an array* can be performed in C only with a for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  a2[i] = a1[i];
}
```

But you're dealing with pointers, so the above only really counts as a shallow copy. You'll need something more interesting to properly deep-copy this array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  a2[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *a2[i] = *a1[i];
}
```

## But what's wrong with `arrayOfNPointers a1 = {1, 2};`?

A lot. `{1, 2}` is not initialising the integers pointed to; it is initialising the pointers.

### Fix 1

Arrays of integers:

```
typedef DataType arrayOfIntegers[N];
arrayOfIntegers a1 = {1, 2};
```

### Fix 2

Properly initialised arrays of pointers to integers:

```
DataType arr[N] = {1, 2};
arrayOfNPointers a1 = {&a[0], &a[1]};
```

Or, if you'd like to use `malloc`ed memory, and allocate it later:

```
arrayOfNPointers a1 = {NULL};
```

The rules of initializer lists ensure tht all the pointers are initially NULL.

Comment: Tired. I normally wouldn't have done something as silly as {1,2}, but more likely what you did (ie: actual pointers rather than integers). Thanks for catching this!

Comment: @Dogbert No worries, it happens to everyone. There was this one time some PHP of mine was broken for days because I tiredly typed `+=` instead of `.=`...

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't assign an array to another. This code will not even compile since you're trying to assign to type `arrayOfPointers` from type `int**`.

Consider a simpler example:

```
int a1[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int a2[3];
a2 = a1;   // will not compile since you're trying to assigning to int[3] from int*
```

Even if you have type-defined

```
typedef int IntArray[3];
IntArray a1 = {1, 2, 3};
IntArray a2;
a2 = a1;
```

This will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

> a2 = a1;    // Safe?

No, The statement won't even compile.
Your compiler will start screaming.

```
main.c: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'arrayOfNPointers' from type 'dataType **'
```